# Why is the apollo cache never used?

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm writing an App using a GraphQL API, with Apollo client.
I try to use the cache, but for some reasons I don't understand, Apollo *never* uses the cache.

```js
function App() {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://example.net/graphql',
  });

  const authMiddleware = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token') ?? '{}');
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token.access_token}` : ''
      },
    };
  });

  // CACHE
  const cache = new InMemoryCache({});

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([authMiddleware, httpLink]),
    cache: cache,
    connectToDevTools: true,
  });

  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(1);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <button onClick={() => {setSomeVar(Math.random())}}>BUTTON1</button>
      <Vehicles someVar={someVar} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

And the query :

```js
interface IVehiclesProps {
  someVar: number,
}
export interface IVehicle {
  id: string,
  __typename: string,
}
const QUERY = gql`
  query vehicles {
    vehicles {
      __typename
      id
    }
  }
`;
function Vehicles(props: IVehiclesProps) {
  const client = useApolloClient();

  function VehiclesQuery(props: any) {
    const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(QUERY);

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Oh no... {error.message}</p>;

    return data.vehicles.map((vehicle: IVehicle) => (
      <div key={vehicle.id}>{vehicle.id}</div>
    ));
  }

  return <>
    <button onClick={() => {
      const read = client.readQuery({query: QUERY});
      console.debug(read)
    }}>BUTTON2</button>
    <VehiclesQuery />
    </>
}
```

Vehicles is a simple component which takes one prop "someVar". Each time I click on BUTTON1, someVar changes, and Vehicles (and VehiclesQuery) are re-rendered.
But the gql query never change, nevertheless the data are *always* refetched from the server, Apollo never uses the cache.
When I click on BUTTON2, I read the cache, and by magic, the cache is full!

I don't understand why Apollo fills the cache, but never wants to use it.

Comment: I have the same issue